# Look for a trick to iter on ocaml type constructors

Tags: ocaml

I have an ocaml type :

```
type t = A | B |  ...
```

and a function to print things about that type :

```
let pp_t fmt x = match x with 
  | A -> Format.fprintf fmt "some nice explanations about A"
  | B -> Format.fprintf fmt "some nice explanations about B"
  | ...
```

How could I write a function to print all the explanations ? Something equivalent to :

```
let pp_all_t fmt = 
   Format.fprintf fmt A;
   Format.fprintf fmt B;
   ...
```

but that would warn me if I forget to add a new constructor. 
It would be even better to have something that automatically build that function,
because my problem is that `t` is quiet big and changes a lot.

I can't imagine how I can "iterate" on the type constructors, but maybe there is a trick...

**EDIT**: What I finally did is :

```
type t = A | B |  ... | Z
let first_t = A
let next_t = function A -> B | B -> C | ... | Z -> raise Not_found
let pp_all_t fmt = 
  let rec pp x = pp_t fmt x ; try let x = next_t x in pp x with Not_found -> ()
  in pp first_t
```

so when I update `t`, the compiler warns me that I have to update `pp_t` and `next_t`, and `pp_all_t` doesn't have to change.
Thanks to you all for the advices.

Comment: Actually, if you add a contructor `C`, ocaml compiler will already warn you in the function `pp_t` that the pattern matching will not be exhaustive and give you the exact case of the missing constructors.

Comment: @cago : yes, thanks, I knew that. My question is more about `pp_all_t'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem for a complicated and evolving type, in practice I would probably write an OCaml program that generates the code from a file containing a list of the values and the associated information.

However, if you had a function `incr_t : t -> t` that incremented a value of type `t`, and if you let the first and last values of t stay fixed, you could write the following:

```
let pp_all_t fmt =
    let rec loop v =
        pp_t fmt v;
        if v < Last_t then loop (incr_t v)
     in
         loop First_t
```

You can't have a general polymorphic `incr_t` in OCaml, because it only makes sense for types whose constructors are nullary (take no values).  But you can write your own `incr_t` for any given type.

This kind of thing is handled quite nicely in Haskell.  Basically, the compiler will write some number of functions for you when the definitions are pretty obvious.  There is a similar project for OCaml called [deriving](http://code.google.com/p/deriving/).  I've never used it, but it does seem to handle the problem of enumerating values.

Since you say you want a "trick", if you don't mind using the unsafe part of OCaml (which I personally *do* mind), you can write `incr_t` as follows:

```
let incr_t (v: t) : t =
    (* Please don't use this trick in real code :-) !  See discussion below.
     *)
    if t < Last_t then
        Obj.magic (Obj.magic v + 1)
    else
        failwith "incr_t: argument out of range"
```

I try to avoid this kind of code if at all possible, it's too dangerous.  For example, it will produce nonsense values if the type `t` gets constructors that take values.  Really it's "an accident waiting to happen".

Comment: Showing `Obj.magic` to beginners is a very bad idea. It encourages bad practice, and there could be a segfault if a non-constant constructor is added. If you think some way of doing things is a bad idea, don't give a working code example!

Comment: I agree completely, I guess I couldn't help myself.  Next time I'll restrain myself.

Comment: @jeffrey: thanks ! it looks great.

@gasche : well, I am not exactly a beginner, but I won't use `Obj.magic` thing ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure why a `incr_t` interface would be preferrable to a (possibly lazy) list of constructors. It looks more complicated to define and to use, with little added flexibility.

Comment: I guess one advantage is you don't have to keep the list up to date as you change your type?  In a complicated case I really might generate the code from a list of constructors.  Many times I've wished for a way to enumerate the values of a type like this (with nullary constructors).

Comment: For "automatic enumeration", metaprogramming solutions are indeed in order (but the complexity cost of deployment can be high enough to make it not always worth it). Besides "deriving" that was suggested by ygrek, Markus Mottl's "type-conv" is also a good choice (well, it doesn't do enumeration out of the box whereas deriving does, but it can help if you want to define other extensions of the kind (which I don't particularly recommend)).

Comment: I agree (I think this is what you're saying) that metaprogramming seems an unweildy tool just for enumerating values of a finite type.  I like the Haskell `deriving Enum` much better.

Answer (score 1):

One needs some form of metaprogramming for such tasks. E.g. you could explore [deriving](http://code.google.com/p/deriving/) to generate `incr_t` from the Jeffrey's answer.

Here is a sample code for the similar task : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1781918/118799

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look but I am not sure that I can add new dependencies to my project.

Comment: Is there a plan to add deriving or something similar to it to the OCaml core?  (seems I recall seeing something about that recently).  It seems like a very useful tool to have in the standard OCaml distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you can do is to define a list of all the constructors:

```
let constructors_t = [A; B; ...]

let pp_all_t = List.iter pp_t constructors_t
```

This is a one-liner, simple to do. Granted, it's slightly redundant (which gray or dark magic would avoid), but it's still probably the best way to go in term of "does what I want" / "has painful side effects" ratio.

Comment: Thanks, but your solution won't warn me if I forget one value in my list... which is my main problem.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how well it will work in this case, but it might be possible to use the new "unused stuff" warning from OCaml 4.00 to be warned if one constructor is forgotten (I'm thinking of type-checking only the type definition plus the list declaration, with the warning enabled). Granted, this kind of manual definition is not as robust as a program-generated code that eg. deriving gives you (or, indirectly, the warning of the pattern-matching exhaustivity checker on Jeffrey's `incr_t` operation).

Comment: I don't use ocaml 4.00 yet : I'll do it soon, and then study the new features of this version. Thanks.